# Drag and Drop in nested dataTables

Tags: jquery, primefaces, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I am using primeface 4.0.

The primeface [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf) only shows how to drag a `draggable` in to a `droppable`.
But then how to drag a that  `draggable` **out of** that `droppable` is never mentioned.

I wantto make a dataTable that:

1. Each `td` cantains a `droppable` panel which multiple `draggable` can be both draged **in to** and **out of**.
2. A back bean object that "keeps data" of this dataTable, which I assume if the dataTable is 2*2, there will be 4 List in the back bean, each stores a list of `draggable` objects of corresponding `droppable` area.

Kinda like a simpler version of`p:schedule` that allows events to be drag and drop between cells.

My efforts:

1. I managed to make some of the functions worked, like drag into a `droppable`
2. But I **can't** make the dragged `draggable` **removed** because there is no ajax event `drag` in `p:draggable` to pass data to back bean, as I did `drop` event in `p:droppable`.(There is a way of using JQuery draggable event `start` and `stop` to pass the col and row num to back bean but I am not sure it's a good way to go)
3. I don't think my implementation is the right way to do it since there are some **bizarre bugs**, like sometimes the dragged object I get from `ddEvent.getData()` is not the right one. (I guess it has something to do with the sole dataSource of `p:droppable`. [Issue1469](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1469))

---

**Update:**
I think the main problem is that `p:droppable` only bind one datasource, so `ddEvent.getData()` will always get the 'object' from binded datasource, my problem is that I have **multiple droppable** area and each need to **bind multiple datasources** .

---

. 
Too bad I couldn't post an screenshot...

Here's my code:
  xthml:
    
    
             Shifts      
    
    
         
    
    
        
        ...

```
<p:columns value="#{scheduleControler.weekdays}" var="date"
    styleClass="schedule_date" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{scheduleControler.weekdays[colIndex]}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="EEE, dd MMM" />
        </h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <!-- Droppable:   -->
    <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
        <p:outputPanel id="dropped">
            <p:dataTable var="shift2"
                value="#{scheduleControler.getDailyShift(employee.id,date)}"
                rendered="#{not empty scheduleControler.getDailyShift(employee.id,date)}">
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputPanel id="shiftBlock2" styleClass="shift_block"
                        style="background-color: \##{shift2.color}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{shift2.name}" />
                    </p:outputPanel>

                    <p:draggable for="shiftBlock2" opacity="0.5" revert="true">
                    </p:draggable>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <!-- Config Droppable: update entire table, pass additional param by attributes -->
    <p:droppable for="dropArea" tolerance="intersect"
        activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource=":shiftTable">
        <f:attribute name="weekday" value="#{date}" />
        <f:attribute name="eid" value="#{employee.id}" />
        <p:ajax event="drop" listener="#{scheduleControler.onShiftDrop}"
            update=" :centerForm:scheduleTbale" />

    </p:droppable>
</p:columns>
```

back bean:

```
 public List<ShiftDto> getDailyShift(String eid, Date date) {
            return this.tmpSchedule.getShifts(eid).get(date);
        }
    public void onShiftDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
            ShiftDto shift = ((ShiftDto) ddEvent.getData());
            Date weekday = (Date) ddEvent.getComponent().getAttributes()
                    .get("weekday");
            String eid = (String) ddEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("eid");
            System.out.println("onShiftDrop: " + shift);
            System.out.println("dropedDate: " + weekday);
            System.out.println("dropedEmployee: " + eid);

            this.tmpSchedule.addShift(eid, weekday, shift);

        }
```

`tmpSchedule` is just a map like container which contains each employee's weekly shifts.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always drag Drag-Drop from one container to another container.**

Say a draggable row in p:table or p:panel within a p:panelgrid (A side) to Droppable p:outPanel (B-side) u'll maintain two List, one for A side and the other for B side.

And make the A-side as droppable and B-side as dragable to have a cyclic Drag-Drop Behaviour(Both will act as datasource to each others droppable tag) and making use of ddEvent.getData to add and remove from the Object List in the controller side.

For the above requirement you can either implement a panelGrid and have multiple relations like this.

OR

Use dragabblerows = "true" and draggableColumns="true" to play around with the rows and columns in the P:table parameter. :p